# FinancialData plot that is based on imported CSV data

Tags: import, curated-data

Is it possible to use the `FinancialData` such as the `PSAR` indicator on imported `CSV` file ?

Comment: Akcmok, welcome to mma.se. Our standard welcome message: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) If you haven't already done so please Take the [tour! ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)  ...

Comment: ... 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use your imported data as input to `TradingChart` and `InteractiveTradingChart` as long as its structure conforms to the pattern {*datelist*, {*open*, *high*, *low*, *close*, *volume*}}:

```
dates = DateRange[{2010, 1, 1}, {2010, 4, 30}];
ohlc = Sort /@ RandomReal[100, {Length@dates, 4}];
ohlc = ohlc[[All, {3, 4, 1, 2}]];
vol = RandomInteger[100, Length@dates];
data = Transpose[{dates, Join[ohlc, List /@ vol, 2]}];

tc = TradingChart[data, {"ParabolicStopAndReversal"}, 
  Appearance -> "Line", ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

2. You can use a built-in `FinancialIndicator` function, e.g. `"ParabolicStopAndReversal"`, outside `TradingChart` or `InteractiveTradingChart` to create a list that you can use with, say, `DateListPlot`:

[ParabolicStopAndReversal](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/indicator/ParabolicStopAndReversal.html)

[image]

```
ClearAll[psar]
psar[a_: .02, b_: .2] := FinancialIndicator["ParabolicStopAndReversal", a, b];
dlp = DateListPlot[{Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2, 4]]}], 
    Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], psar[][data]}] }, 
   Joined -> {True, False}, ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.03]];
```

[image]

Comment: kglr, this is of great help

Comment: @Akcmok, glad it was useful. Welcome to mma.se.